# Re-create the "group" tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

Back in April 2016, I created the [group](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group) tag. Its excerpt got [approved on April 9, 2016](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76922) and it was used for multiple questions about the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module (note: I'm not a (co-)maintainer of it ...). For sure it was not that it got deleted automatically again since it was not used in any, or only 1, question.

But for reasons that are not clear to me, the tag got deleted anyway (and more or less right away). On April 11, 2016, the tag was recreated, and I created the [excerpt](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76966) and the [tag wiki](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76965) again. Sure enough, a bit later the tag disappeared again (automatically, but only after a moderator removed the tag from all questions again that were using it).

Today, there are various questions that are related to the Group module, such as (not sure if the list is complete ...):

- [How to programmatically add content to a group in the Group Module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207710)
- [How do I change the site name in the .theme file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206740)
- [How to display a views block on pages with a specific combination of URL patterns?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206455)
- [How to restrict user role to see only their members profile?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200415)
- [How to show the content of a group on the group page when using the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197552)
- [What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)
- [How to bulk assign existing content to a group created with the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197489)
- [How do I get the list of all group members?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171073)
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171310
- [How to email all group members after a new node is added when using the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170910)

Since as of today there is no tag specific to the Group module, some users don't realize some of the group specific questions is about the Group module. Have a look at questions such as [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171073) for an interesting illustration, i.e.:

- its revision history (about multiple retaggings).
- the comments (about how some users confuse "`group`" with "`og`")

Sure I have all the privileges myself to create the tag, document the tag excerpt and tag wiki (this time I even wouldn't need approvals like before anymore). But I don't want to take the risk that doing so myself would be considered as an unacceptable user action (since a moderator already caused the tag I created before to be deleted again).

Therefor, can anybody please recreate the [group](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group) tag ... again? Hoping that this time we can be sure that the tag is there to stay ...

For anybody who wonders if this tag makes sense, here are some quotes from some other meta tag questions:

- From an answer to "[How do we respond to requests to create tags?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/769)":

  > The criterion I normally use to understand if the tag is necessary is: Is there an expert behind that tag? For example, to answer questions tagged [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views), you need to know the Views module; to answer [form-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-api) questions, you need to know the form API; there isn't an expert that answers to [error](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) questions, which would be any question about code showing an error. In the latter case, the tag is too broad to be helpful.
- From some comments to "[Can we get a Twitter Bootstrap tag?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2869)":

  > - Can you provide some examples of questions where this would be appropriate?
  > - ... since you are making the proposal, you should really provide some backup evidence as to why it would benefit the site. It is the way the SE sites work.

**Update**: it would be interesting to learn about the motivation for the introduction (by a moderator ...) of the not yet documented [rng](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rng) tag recently in [these (9) questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rng?sort=active) ... including any potential reasons why that tag would make sense.

Comment: Tags shouldn't be created arbitrarily, it happens organically when a new question has need for it. The word "Group" is too ambiguous for a tag in my opinion, especially for such a tiny number of questions as 9, but I think something like "group-module" would be fine

Comment: @Clive There was a time (early 2015) that there where X.module tags ... Later on they all got destroyed. Also, what's wrong in calling calling a cat a cat? Ie use the group tag for the group module? Similar to Views called Views (even though there are also questions about page "views" ...). Also, are you saying  a rollback to a prior version of relevant questions I quoted (which were all new and which I think still need them) is OK?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. You'd know if I was, because I would have said it. Please do not try to put words into people's mouths, it's a most distasteful thing to do. Regarding the issue: "cat" == "cat", "group" != "group module". So the analogy doesn't hold. If I had to guess why that tag was originally removed, I would assume it's because people were using it for everything they thought was related to the concept of a group. So stuff about general grouping of users, Organic Groups, etc. I don't see the need for anything to change here, personally. Not worth it for a measly 9 questions.

Comment: But I'm also not opposed to it enough to fight it. If consensus is that "Group" is useful tag, then yeah, let's create it

Comment: "I" think some "module" suffix would make a lot of sense (early 2015 it got rejected, eg to use charts.module, or chart.module). Could help also for  "workflow" versus "workflow module", or "flags" versus "flag module". FYI: The group tag "was" only used for questions about the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module ... And the last phrase in a previous comment (= ... 9 questions) seems to imply that [these 36 tags](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags?page=11&tab=popular) and [these 36 tags](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags?page=12&tab=popular) may need review also ...

Comment: You're assuming that every tag that exists has been created with massive amounts of thought and reference back to a set of rules, or that those rules even exist in any real form - that isn't really the case. I can't comment on the relative merits of each tag that you find's existence, no, I can just comment on the one you've written the question about. As far as I'm concerned there isn't really a strong argument for or against it, so I'll defer to the community

Comment: As side note, a suggested edit for a tag wiki doesn't mean the community accepts to use the tag. Most of the users approving the tag wiki just look at the tag wiki being helpful in itself, not to how much helpful the tag is. It is like users approving a suggested edit for a question; if they approve the suggested edit, it doesn't mean they think the question should not be closed.

Comment: The issue with tags is how they are misused. If a tag keeps getting used instead of another one, it means the tag has been badly named. If there are X questions using a tag, and in most of the cases it is associated with another one, it means the other tag should probably be used.

Comment: Finally, it is the community that needs to edit out the questions wrongly using a tag; if the community fails in that, it means the community doesn't understand how to use the tag, or the community doesn't care of that tag. Adding a tag to a question is just the first step.

Comment: Where was the discussion on tag disambiguation? So long as you don't require every module to be tagged as "-module" (etc.), I think [tag:group-module] would be useful and clear. Compare, for example, at Travel.SE: [georgia-country](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/georgia-country) and [georgia-usa](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/georgia-usa), but [bhutan](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhutan) and [north-dakota](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-dakota)

Comment: @choster : I don't understand your first question in your comment (can you retry?). But I seem to understand from your comment that you agree with "some" tag dedicated to the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module. Even though I personally would prefer just "group", I'd be OK with a group-module compromise ... Be my guest to apply such tag to (eg) one or more of the questions I included in my question here (if I see such edit suggestions showing up in the suggested edits review queue, "I" will approve them, for sure. BTW: flag-module, workflow-module, notifications-module, ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Sorry, I thought you meant earlier that group-module had been rejected in the past, but I couldn't locate any such discussion.

Comment: @choster: no need for sorry ... check the links in the first 2 pargs of my question here. The tag "group" has been created twice (+ documented with excerpt and tag wiki), and each time a moderator remove the tag afterwards from all questions that were using that tag. So it depends what you mean by "rejected", but probably a better phrasing is something like "a moderator believes the group tag has no reason-to-exist". "I" however do think a tag dedicated to this module does make sense (and if not, then there are dozens of other tags that should not exist either).

Answer (score 2):

People don't put *that much* thought into tagging and this SE site isn't big enough to utilize tagging like SO (e.g. filtering new questions that I only have interest/knowledge in). Further, Drupal is filled with many overloaded, abstract terms (e.g. node, view) that are destined to be mis-tagged. I say a good rule of thumb is to glance at a project's popularity to be sure ***it is a well-known thing*** by most Drupallers (e.g. Views, Token, Webform, Date). If it's not that popular, has overloaded meanings, and is not clear what are people tagging it for, it probably shouldn't be a tag.

Comment: *shrug* Whenever you have a site driven by more than one person, with rules that subject to interpretation, you're never going to get consistent action with regards to policy. Perhaps the approver noticed the [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/rng) is explicitly promoting this site as the venue for support requests.

Comment: Yes, the project owner redirects users to us for support requests, but Stack Exchange is not for support requests, generally speaking. We cannot give support for each issue that could happen on a site, in the same way the Drupal core issue queue is not thought for that.